# JSTL - how to update a variable with application scope

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, el

In my homepage I get a list of items (in this case a list of concert venues) from its corresponding servlet, which gets them from the database:

```
<c:set var="venues" value="${allVenues}" scope="application" />
```

, where ${allVenues} was sent from the servlet as

```
req.setAttribute("allVenuesAdmin", allVenues);
```

In my admin page I can add, update, delete venues to/from the database and make the servlet for the admin page send the new list of venues, again with the setAttribute method.

How do I then update the list in the "venues" variable of the application scope with the new list I get from the admin page servlet?

Comment: I ended up writing a servlet for each page and getting the info from the database in page scope. Is this good practice?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the PageContext in your servlet, you can use this code:

```
pageContext.setAttribute("venues", allVenues, PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

this updates the corresponding object in the application context.

If you have a request variable "allVenuesAdmin" (e.g. a List) and want to update the application scope variable "venues" in JSTL, you can use

```
<c:set var="venues" value="${allVenuesAdmin}" scope="application" />
```

in you JSP.

Comment: From what I've read, this is JSP, not java. So I have to write it in the page. But how do I make it update my data whenever I invoke the doPost from the servlet?

Comment: I used it in my page, but it updates my "venues" var as a String, not as a set of venue beans. How do I do this with EL?